# Angular Service utilizando packages de terceiro

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou criando um `service` em `angular` que consome um package para consultar uma `api`, porém recebo sempre o mesmo erro;

> Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService: (?).

o Código:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { WooCommerceAPI } from 'woocommerce-api';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  woocommerce: any;

  constructor(@Inject(WooCommerceAPI) woocommerce: WooCommerceAPI) {
    this.woocommerce = woocommerce({
    url: 'http://wc-project.dev/',
    consumerKey: 'ck_123',
    consumerSecret: 'cs_123',
    wpAPI: true,
    version: 'wc/v2'
  });
}

  getProducts(): any {
    return this.woocommerce.get('products');
  }
}
```

Já tentei utilizar com `OnInit` mas recebo o erro

> this.woocommerce is undefined

como a função `ngOnInit` é iniciada antes mesmo da declaração dos atributos até entendo esse erro.

Mas como posso utilizar o package da api em meu `service` ?

Answer (score 1):

Como a API não faz parte do Angular você precisa importar tudo com `*` e associar diretamente a uma variável na hora do import.

Você também não precisa colocar dentro do constructor já que ele não possui nenhum provider.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  woocommerce: any;

  constructor() {
    this.woocommerce = WooCommerceAPI ({
    url: 'http://wc-project.dev/',
    consumerKey: 'ck_123',
    consumerSecret: 'cs_123',
    wpAPI: true,
    version: 'wc/v2'
  });
}

  getProducts(): any {
    return this.woocommerce.get('products');
  }
}
```